# Getting System.UnauthorizedAccessException when trying to fetch files from network

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, shared-directory

I have the following code:

```
var pathRoot = Path.GetPathRoot("\\\\192.168.10.106");
var dataFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(pathRoot);
var filesInsideDataFolder = await dataFolder.GetFilesAsync();
foreach (var item in filesInsideDataFolder)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

In my manifest i have setup the following capabilities:

```
<Capability Name="internetClient" />
<Capability Name="videosLibrary" />
<Capability Name="enterpriseAuthentication" />
<Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
<Capability Name="musicLibrary" />
<Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />
<Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
```

Why is it so that i get System.UnauthorizedAccessException when using:

```
dataFolder.GetFilesAsync()
```

But not when using:

```
dataFolder.GetItemsAsync()
```

And when using the last method i only get folders.

I have tried to disable the firewall and turn off my antivirus.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did know i had to set up file type associations for this to work. After adding

```
<Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
      <FileTypeAssociation Name="mpeg4">
        <DisplayName>MP4</DisplayName>
        <Logo>mp4.png</Logo>
        <InfoTip>Mpeg 4 video file</InfoTip>
        <SupportedFileTypes>
          <FileType ContentType="video/mp4">.mp4</FileType>
        </SupportedFileTypes>
      </FileTypeAssociation>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

Now i get mp4 files listed.